# NativeScript StackLayout with gap between child elements

Tags: nativescript

I'm using the NativeScript StackLayout component to layout my elements.

What is the best approach to create a gap between the child elements of a StackLayout?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `margin` in the css for that layout.

In you XML:

```
  <StackLayout>
      <Label text="Hey there,"></Label>
      <Label text="world!"></Label>
  </StackLayout>
```

In your css:

```
StackLayout Label {
  margin: 10;
}
```

Comment: Thx. I'm using margin-top in a Vertical oriented container so it only affects the direction of the layout.